# How can be handle oracle decimal types with GoldenGate "Kafka" / "Kafka connect" handler?

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, cdc, oracle-golden-gate

I wanna use Oracle GoldenGate (it's orcale cdc tool) to integrate oracle with Kafka.
i have find a two Handler:

1. http://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/bd123110/gg-bd/GADBD/using-kafka-connect-handler.htm#GADBD-GUID-81730248-AC12-438E-AF82-48C7002178EC with avro formatter
2. http://docs.oracle.com/goldengate/bd123110/gg-bd/GADBD/using-kafka-handler.htm#GADBD449

Both this handler do not support decimal type(i mean they do not treat decimal in avro as logical type, or else how), this tools just convert decimal to double type. And in this case, we loose precision.

Does any one know a good way to treat decimals, except write own handler?

Comment: I prefer use confluent's  kafka connect handler, because it  resolve problem of schema evolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 12.3.1.1.4 and the following:

```
gg.handler.<name>.format.mapLargeNumbersAsStrings=false
gg.handler.<name>.format.enableDecimalLogicalType=true
gg.handler.<name>.format.enableTimestampLogicalType=true
```

Comment: yes i see that new release has this feature. But our company use 11.X oracle. And will not migrate to new one in neares two year. So i just migrate CDC to XStream API. Also i check Debezium, but it was in Alpha when i try.